# connection to microsoft azure sql database works in local enviornment but not in production

Tags: python, sql, azure, flask, database-connection

I am trying to open a web service app that will allow me to connect to the database on azure with python code, Ive tried using `sqlalchemy` and `pyodbc` and i am successfully able to connect to the database on my machine, in the local host, i can perform all necessary actions i want to there. but i want to be able to set this code up to be able to hit specific routes in an ajax call that can perform certain actions on my database, like flipping a users active flag to false. however the problem is that when i upload the python code to azure, using this guide here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask) it just returns a 500 server error, i cant find anything in the trace as to why its not working, I thought that it might just be that my local machine is whitelisted in the IP address's to the database, but even still if i add that app services IP address to the allowed IP's it still returns a server error. here is the setup of the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def connection():
    Driver = "{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}"
    Server = "server string"
    Port = 1433
    Database = "dbname"
    Uid = "user"
    Pwd = "pass"
    
    try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={Driver};SERVER={Server};DATABASE={Database};Uid={Uid};Pwd={Pwd};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM (Database Table) where id = 999999999;")

    for row in cursor:
        print('row = %r' % (row,))
    return "Connection to database successful"
```

I ommitted certain details but the syntax should remain intact, Again, in my local machine I can connect to the database and return data. but once it compiles the code in azure, it no longer works.

**excuse the `try` statement. I was trying to catch the error and send it to the client in hopes of gathering more information from the 500 error, but it didnt work.**

**Edit: its worth mentioning that if i remove the actual connection string and anything to do with connecting to the database, the code will return `"connection to database successful"` this leads me to believe that it isnt fully making a connection to the database at all. and thats why its erroring out, however the question remains, why can i connect in my local enviornment but not in azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short answer to this is the App service was missing the driver `{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}` it wasn't erroring out locally because I have that driver installed locally, but this driver isn't available in the app. To get this to work I would have to install the App to a Virtual Machine to be able to download the driver appropriately.

fortunately however Azure web apps built on a linux base already come with `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}` So flipping the driver from 13 to 17 allowed the app to successfully connect to my Database.

Comment: Thank you for answering your question, your solution also worked for me.

Comment: @MoonLight Your welcome, know too that the first answer was very helpful in getting to this result. the remote debugging tools is what allowed me to successfully get to that point, but the answer, as to why it wasnt connecting, is that, the odbc driver.

Answer (score 1):

have you heard about remote debugging in azure. This is the best tool to trace out errors using your visual studio code or VS where you web or app is initially working well. You can use multiple methods to debug line by line or cluster by cluster. Kindly check it out here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Comment: I have not. But ill give this documentation a good look over soon. Hopefully it'll give me more details about why its erroring out.

Comment: This turned out to be the most useful route, i was able to look at the logs from the app service cloud and this led me to find out why it wasnt working correctly thanks for the tip!